# replace string with string2 ONLY on line starting with '//FIXME'

Tags: bash, sed, grep, find

I have multiple files with a line that has 'date' that should be 'data' but the change should only be made where date is on the same line as "FIXME"

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type -f \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \) -exec grep FIXME {} \; | sed 's/date/data/g'
```

will output the changes but if i add `-i` to sed i get errors.
so i cant get changes written to disk this way. 
I think it's because sed only gets access to buffer contents grep pull up and does not know anything about the file it came from. i'm guessing.
-Thank you!

Comment: Can't you do `grep "date.*FIXME" | sed 's/date/data/g'`?

Comment: @l19: OP wants to replace the original file. Yours will just *output* the substituted result.

Comment: @justhalf, I meant to say that he could edit his command from `-exec` onwards.

Comment: i can't get that to work. if it looks in all the files in the current dir that's fine. but no subdirectories. the line i want to find is looks like "//FIXME bla bla date bla bla" if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `-maxdepth 1` otherwise it doesn't traverse to sub directories. Also sed command needs to be corrected. Try this:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \) -exec sed -i.bak '/FIXME/s/date/data/g' '{}' \;
```